# .NET CORE MVC - Generic solution to filter different tables

Tags: filter, frameworks, graphql, asp.net-core-mvc, odata

Currently I am developing a complex management system in .Net Core 2.2 MVC with many different tables. Each table should have the possibility of filters, sorting and page numbering.

Each table has a different database entity and has no similarity to the other tables.

Is there a way to generate a general solution using OData or Entity Framework or other Framework without having to implement each filer, sort or page numbering in each individual case? It should be a generic solution which could be annotated to controller action methods to enable filtering and so on.

The filter should be made by server and not with javascript.

I thank you for your opinion and suggestions. Enclosed two pictures of affected tables:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework has a set of generic tools to call a table given an `TEntityType`.
I guess the hardest part is to build the filters dynamically, given an input from the front-end.

### On back-end side

What you might search for (on back-end side) is a way to build lambda expressions dynamically like this :

```
string myFilterString = "entity => entity.EntityProperty > 100";

Predicate<MyEntity> myFilterPredicate = MyPredicateFactory.BuildFromString<MyEntity>(myFilterString);

var filteredEntities = context.Set<MyEntity>().Where(myFilterPredicate).ToList();
```

And you would receive the `filterString` from the front, which would have the responsibility to build it with the UI it deserves.

It's doable, let's check this article on a way to do it for a simple example. You could use reflection to build expressions of any given type.
https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/

### On front-end side

To avoid always keeping in sync front-end and backend, whenever the backend evolves (a property is renamed for example),What I suggest is to dynamically build (back-end side) a json schema of the usable filterable entities and properties, and send it to the front one way or another, so that when the front gets it, it knows which entity or property names are usable to build the string filters.

By doing this, you can rename or add properties in the back without bothering with front end compatibility. Your front would just be able to manipulate the new properties.

### Optional : other interesting tracks

In case you don't know GraphQL APIs, you may be interested to check what it is worth, since with a bit of configuration and code, it supports filtering from client-side.